# FFT Size in jTransforms

Tags: size, signal-processing, fft, resolution, frequency

I need to calculate the FFT of audiodata in an Android Project and I use jTransforms to achieve this.

The samples of the audiodata are a few seconds long and are recorded with a samplerate of 11025 Hertz.

I am not sure how to set the length of the FFT in jTransforms.
I do not really need high frequency resolution, so a size of 1024 would be enough.

But from what I have understood learning about the FFT, if I decrease the FFT size F and use a sample with a lenght of N > F, only the first F values of the original sample are transformed.

Is that true or did I understand something wrong?

If it is true, is there an efficient way to tranform the whole signal and decreasing the FFT-Size afterwards?

I need this to classify different signals using Support Vector Machines, and FFT-Sizes > 1024 would give me too much features as output, so I would have to reduce the result of the FFT to a more compact vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the FFT magnitude results, then use the FFT repeatedly on successive 1024 chunk lengths of data, and vector sum all the successive magnitude results to get an estimate for the entire much longer signal.

See [Welch's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) on estimating spectral density for an explanation of why this might be a useful technique.

Comment: Incredible, i get an accuracy of 100%  in my classification with your approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Im not familiar with the jTransform library, but do you really set the size of the transform before calculating it? Amplitude values of the time-domain signal and the sampling frequency (11.025 kHz) is enough to calculate the FFT (note that the FFT assumes constant sampling rate)

The resolution in frequency domain will be determined by Nyquist's theorem; the maximum resolvable frequency in your signal will be equal to half your sampling rate. In other words, sampling your signal with 11.025 kHz, you can expect your frequency graph to contain frequency values (and corresponding amplitudes) between 0 Hz - 5.5125 kHz.

UPDATE:

The resolution of the FFT (the narrowness of the frequency bins) will increase/improve if your input signal is longer, thus 1024 samples might not be a long sequence enough if you need to distinguish between very small changes in frequency. If thats not a problem for you application, and the nature of your data is not variying quickly, and you have the processing time, then taking an average of 3-4 FFT estimates will greatly reduce noise and improve estimates.

Comment: Yes. First I create a DoubleFFT_1D Object and set the FFT Size in the constructor. Then I can transform double[] with the method .realForward();. I don't need that much frequency resolution, but the transformation should cover the whole input and not only the first 1024 frames.